# Unable to Reach web application after a few days time

Tags: java, tomcat, server, catalina

I have a web application running on a local tomcat server that after a few days becomes unreachable. Looking through the tomcat logs, I find the logs below. Any idea what's going on here? Simply restarting tomcat solves the issues for another few days to a week

```
15-Oct-2019 06:34:26.792 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-149] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/powersync] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.commit(Http11OutputBuffer.java:351)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:167)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:207)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:375)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:420)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:999)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:425)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to HotSwap which you are likely using in your application server. Hotswap will give you the ability to make changes to a running application freely without having to restart the server, so long as you are making modifications to existing methods. From my understanding, it seems like you are maintaining the server running in your application for extended periods of time. This is typically done by developers running their application using things like Hotswap or [JRebel](https://jrebel.com/software/jrebel/trial/).

The issue that you are experiencing is due to the way that Hotswap works within your JVM. Hotswap actually adds resources within your JVM as you are making modifications in your application. The problem that happens is that it will eventually make the JVM crash due to these modifications. As long as you are using Hotswap, you will have to regularly restart the JVM after a period of time.

JRebel, on the other hand, will actually provide you with the ability to see changes in your JVM without ever having to restart the JVM. The reason for this is due to the fact that JRebel doesn't move resources but rather remaps your classloaders within the JVM to the files modified locally through your IDE of choice.

I am an engineer for the JRebel team at Perforce Software. But the issue you are experiencing is something I regularly run into with developers running their application with Hotswap. I hope that this is helpful.